# In C++, function returning vector of custom data structure throwing a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, vector

My program compiles, the problem is at runtime.

I have the following program in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct SpotifyRelease {
    std::string release_date, id, href, name;
};


SpotifyRelease get_release(const std::string id, const std::string href, const std::string name, const std::string release_date) {
    SpotifyRelease sr;
    sr.id = id;
    sr.href = href;
    sr.name = name;
    sr.release_date = release_date;
    return sr;
}

std::vector<SpotifyRelease> spotify_get_latest_releases() {
    std::vector<SpotifyRelease> v1;
    std::vector<SpotifyRelease>::iterator it;
    v1.insert(it, get_release("1OyADPvYTlmT5hV0mtxLAY", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1OyADPvYTlmT5hV0mtxLAY", "Bloom", "2018-08-31"));
    v1.insert(it, get_release("3HNnxK7NgLXbDoxRZxNWiR", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/3HNnxK7NgLXbDoxRZxNWiR", "Kamikaze", "2018-08-31"));
    v1.insert(it, get_release("1Xf5RZ7zQjF2WEkk7KpZVi", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1Xf5RZ7zQjF2WEkk7KpZVi", "Superhero", "2018-08-30"));
    v1.insert(it, get_release("317hvEJEf6RTxPT4m2NiRb", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/317hvEJEf6RTxPT4m2NiRb", "4Freedom", "2018-08-30"));
    v1.insert(it, get_release("6ggnUqpjfkDULwX0dr164j", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/6ggnUqpjfkDULwX0dr164j", "XTCY", "2018-08-30"));
    v1.insert(it, get_release("6ST7naJFCe9iBeOleU5Ccu", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/6ST7naJFCe9iBeOleU5Ccu", "Michael Jackson x Mark Ronson: Diamonds are Invincible", "2018-08-29"));
    v1.insert(it, get_release("6OX3blc5vb3huGk2PTM0Kk", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/6OX3blc5vb3huGk2PTM0Kk", "The Dark Side / Something Human / Thought Contagion / Dig Down", "2018-08-30"));
    v1.insert(it, get_release("4o8Y3L9WQvk3L3u9M0gngq", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/4o8Y3L9WQvk3L3u9M0gngq", "Don't Leave Me Alone (feat. Anne-Marie) [Oliver Heldens Remix]", "2018-08-31"));
    v1.insert(it, get_release("0LOJHhz9ybWLVMLucHYtCe", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/0LOJHhz9ybWLVMLucHYtCe", "REMEDY", "2018-08-31"));
    v1.insert(it, get_release("1d1MKgYRqFUs8Mner4uF4y", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1d1MKgYRqFUs8Mner4uF4y", "Hola", "2018-08-31"));
    v1.insert(it, get_release("3qX5J1RkaFxSXEqRc8Qzmo", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/3qX5J1RkaFxSXEqRc8Qzmo", "Amigos Con Derechos", "2018-08-31"));
    v1.insert(it, get_release("3OLSEsIMEgtcn1U9s03qRR", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/3OLSEsIMEgtcn1U9s03qRR", "BEBE", "2018-08-31"));
    v1.insert(it, get_release("2qIbHfs93z6eDwGoAdCkXA", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/2qIbHfs93z6eDwGoAdCkXA", "8 Letters", "2018-08-31"));
    v1.insert(it, get_release("3LBRCisCaxgQjb5nwSMPgU", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/3LBRCisCaxgQjb5nwSMPgU", "Big Red Machine", "2018-08-31"));
    v1.insert(it, get_release("29KdLwIDFZ8DSSgxOQ8kLa", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/29KdLwIDFZ8DSSgxOQ8kLa", "Love Wins", "2018-08-31"));
    v1.insert(it, get_release("1aG5r6TZdMVUeNGY6Lf4YP", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1aG5r6TZdMVUeNGY6Lf4YP", "Never Comin Down", "2018-08-31"));
    v1.insert(it, get_release("0AykQgBtKmWJkQvomIKYSF", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/0AykQgBtKmWJkQvomIKYSF", "Rotation 112th (feat. Rich The Kid) [Remix]", "2018-08-31"));
    v1.insert(it, get_release("28cah7y6l6TUl5G7aP5pZf", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/28cah7y6l6TUl5G7aP5pZf", "Serious", "2018-08-30"));
    v1.insert(it, get_release("1xKEX6KhO9pRM85WT7aOel", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1xKEX6KhO9pRM85WT7aOel", "Weed Garden", "2018-08-31"));
    v1.insert(it, get_release("5eOlKFDAN9dXwYycRqEmnP", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/5eOlKFDAN9dXwYycRqEmnP", "Flow State", "2018-08-31"));
    return v1;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<SpotifyRelease> latest_releases;
    SpotifyRelease release;
    latest_releases = spotify_get_latest_releases();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is when I try to run the program, my program exits with code 11 in the second line of `int main()`

I am not really sure why, as the program looks okay to me.

Any help in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pass an uninitialised iterator to `insert`. That's undefined behaviour.

You probably meant something like `auto it = begin(v1);`, but this still wouldn't work, because you don't reassign `it` anywhere, and `std::vector::insert` may invalidate all existing iterators to the vector's elements.

I guess you don't really want to use `insert` anyway. Just use `push_back`:

```
v1.push_back(get_release("1OyADPvYTlmT5hV0mtxLAY", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1OyADPvYTlmT5hV0mtxLAY", "Bloom", "2018-08-31"));
// ...
```

Comment: `Insert()` may invalidate existing iterators *but returns a valid one*.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist: Yes, of course. But using `push_back` is easier.

Comment: Definitely friend, no disagreement. I just figured since the OP asked about what's wrong with *his usage* of `std::vector`'s interface that perhaps he can gain from knowing. But I'm rather new trying to answer questions so maybe it's irrelevant to mention so.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're calling `insert()` with an *uninitialized, invalid* `iterator`. To make it work you need both to initialize the iterator and keep it valid by updating it from the *return value* of `insert()`, like this:

```
std::vector<SpotifyRelease>::iterator it{v1.begin()};
it = v1.insert(it, get_release("1OyADPvYTlmT5hV0mtxLAY", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1OyADPvYTlmT5hV0mtxLAY", "Bloom", "2018-08-31"))++;
...
```

But it seems simpler in your case to just change those `v1.insert(...);` lines to be without the `iterator` alltogether:

```
v1.push_back(get_release("1OyADPvYTlmT5hV0mtxLAY", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1OyADPvYTlmT5hV0mtxLAY", "Bloom", "2018-08-31"));
...
```

Or better yet, no need using `get_release()` at all in the absence of further unspecified reason -- you can save yourself all the potential copying back and forth and just do this:

```
v1.push_back({"1OyADPvYTlmT5hV0mtxLAY", "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1OyADPvYTlmT5hV0mtxLAY", "Bloom", "2018-08-31"});
...
```

Comment: The iterator is not *invalidated*. It's *invalid* to begin with.